# Tensorflow inception-V3 Re-Train multiple layers

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have successfully retrained inception V3 final classification layer using Python2.7 api for my own 100 classes and it is giving decent results, but not exceptionally good.

I also have the code to retrain the whole network from scratch as given [here (google code)](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception) but that is resource and time intensive and I have 400 000 images, so don't know what will be the accuracy after training.

I was wondering if I can retrain some of the last few fully connected layers, or more than only the classification layer so that accuracy can be improved to some extent, and it is also not computationally very demanding in terms of resources and time.

I tried to search a lot, but couldn't find anything. It is possible what I want to do? and I need help on this.

Answer (score -1):

Optimizers look at a list of "trainable variables". A reference to this array is available using `tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)`. You should be able to modify that. A read-only version is `tf.trainable_variables`.

Note that the forward step (inference) will always have to run, so you have to pay that cost. If you don't want that, the easiest is to run the inference, save the output to tf records, then train out of these pre-processed data samples.